# How to iterate the split result array of a multiline string value in order to reformat certain lines / newlines?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, multiline

I have a string of data that has line feeds in the middle.
For example:

```
"Product Name \n Product Color \n Product Quantity \n Product Location \n Product Size \n Product Power"
```

The Amount of elements in the string could be infinite.

I need to replace the `\n` with `>>>> \n` but only when the line numbers are greater than 3 and not the last line. On the last line I need it to say `(end)`

I have tried map, and I can split and replace, but I'm having trouble iterating through the array to identify the lines that are to be modified.
As well as joining them back up once all lines are modified or not.

Input is:

```
"Retract-A-Banner\n**Template:\nFull Color\nImprint Information:\nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing\n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network\n"
```

Expected Output:

```
"Retract-A-Banner\n**Template:\nFull Color >>>> \nImprint Information: >>>> \nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing >>>> \n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network(end)\n"
```

Comment: What is the input and what is the output? Show examples

Comment: Input is:
"Retract-A-Banner\n**Template:\nFull Color\nImprint Information:\nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing\n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network\n"

Expected Output:"Retract-A-Banner\n**Template:\nFull Color >>>> \nImprint Information: >>>> \nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing >>>> \n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network(end)\n"

Comment: Are you looking for a literal "backslash + n" or a newline character?

Comment: How are consecutive newline characters are going to be handled? Continue counting? Handling it as a single newline and sanitize/replace it accordingly too?

Comment: It is would be the literal backslash and n as it will remain a string, and the application that evaluates the code will handle the actual process of a new line. 

consecutive new line characters would be handled the same until there is an end.

Comment: @DavidRomstad in that case the string literal should have `\\n`; I updated my answer - see if that's what you mean

Comment: @DavidRomstad ... Regarding all the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @PeterSeliger These approaches and solutions have proved very helpful. A very diverse group of answers, great insight and practice on different methods. Appreciate all of the answers. The most succinct answer however for my situation was the
Split by \n and recreate your string with the conditions:

if this is the last one so add (end)
if line is greater than 3, add >>>> \n
otherwise a simple \n will be fine
EDIT:

add a check whether the last string is \n, and remove that value from the array.

Comment: @DavidRomstad ... glad you found the answers helpful especially in terms of learning. One polite thing of yours then was to still accept *Omri's* answer since you consider it the best provided one.

Answer (score 2):

Split by `\n` and recreate your string with the conditions:

1. if this is the last one so add `(end)`
2. if line is greater than 3, add `>>>> \n`
3. otherwise a simple `\n` will be fine

EDIT:

add a check whether the last string is `\n`, and remove that value from the array.

```js
const str = "Retract-A-Banner\n**Template:\nFull Color\nImprint Information:\nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing\n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network\n";

const splitted = str.split('\n');
let output = '';

if (splitted[splitted.length - 1] === '')
  splitted.length--;
  
for (let i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
  if (i + 1 === splitted.length) {
    output += splitted[i] + ' (end)';
  } else if (i >= 2) {
    output += splitted[i] + ' >>>> \n';
  } else {
    output += splitted[i] + '\n';
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: One needs to decide upon the last line's value how to concatenate the result. As for now, the current result doesn't equal the OP's expected value due to the last line being an empty string value ... `''`. There is also a line mis-count for the concatenation of `'  >>>>  \n'`

Comment: One minor thing yet ... the code change from `... } else if (i >= 3) { ... ` to  `... } else if (i >= 2) { ... `.

Answer (score 2):

Actually one does not necessarily need to choose an iterating approach for the [`.split(/\n/)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/split) operation's result array.

The next introduced approach instead works with a straightforward data access (for all the information needed) via ...

- [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) and
- [`Array.prototype.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

And the return value gets assembled on the spot (depending on the last line's value) utilizing ...

- [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and
- [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
function parseNewlines(value) {

  const[ line1, line2, ...rest ] = String(value).split(/\n/);
  const lastLine = rest.pop();

  return [
    `${ line1 }\n${ line2 }\n${ rest.join(' >>>> \n') }`,

    (lastLine === '')
      && `(end)\n`
      || ` >>>> \n${ lastLine }(end)`,

  ].join('');
}

const originalTestValue = `Retract-A-Banner
**Template:
Full Color
Imprint Information:
CL: 488 Special Ops Wing
353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network
` // be aware of the last line.

const alteredTestValue = `Retract-A-Banner
**Template:
Full Color
Imprint Information:
CL: 488 Special Ops Wing
353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network` // be aware of the last line.

// be aware of the last line.
const expectedResult = `Retract-A-Banner\n**Template:\nFull Color >>>> \nImprint Information: >>>> \nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing >>>> \n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network(end)\n`;

// be aware of the last line.
const expectedResultOfAlteredValue = `Retract-A-Banner\n**Template:\nFull Color >>>> \nImprint Information: >>>> \nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing >>>> \n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network(end)`;

console.log(
  `OP's use case ...\n${ parseNewlines(originalTestValue) }`
);
console.log(
  `altered use case ...\n${ parseNewlines(alteredTestValue) }`
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "OP's use case ...\ntest passed ?..",
  (parseNewlines(originalTestValue) === expectedResult)
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "altered use case ...\ntest passed ?..",
  (parseNewlines(alteredTestValue) === expectedResult)
);
console.log(
  "altered use case and altered expectation ...\ntest passed ?..",
  (parseNewlines(alteredTestValue) === expectedResultOfAlteredValue)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Nevertheless an iterating approach could be implemented with a classic [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task.

```js
function parseNewlines(value) {
  return String(value)

    .split(/\n/)
    .reduce((result, line, idx, arr) => {
      return [

        result,
        (idx < (arr.length - 1))

          ? `${ (idx >= 3) && ' >>>> ' || '' }\n${ line }`
          : (line === '')
              && `(end)\n`
              || ` >>>> \n${ line }(end)`,

      ].join('');
    });
}

const originalTestValue = `Retract-A-Banner
**Template:
Full Color
Imprint Information:
CL: 488 Special Ops Wing
353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network
` // be aware of the last line.

const alteredTestValue = `Retract-A-Banner
**Template:
Full Color
Imprint Information:
CL: 488 Special Ops Wing
353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network` // be aware of the last line.

// be aware of the last line.
const expectedResult = `Retract-A-Banner\n**Template:\nFull Color >>>> \nImprint Information: >>>> \nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing >>>> \n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network(end)\n`;

// be aware of the last line.
const expectedResultOfAlteredValue = `Retract-A-Banner\n**Template:\nFull Color >>>> \nImprint Information: >>>> \nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing >>>> \n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network(end)`;

console.log(
  `OP's use case ...\n${ parseNewlines(originalTestValue) }`
);
console.log(
  `altered use case ...\n${ parseNewlines(alteredTestValue) }`
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "OP's use case ...\ntest passed ?..",
  (parseNewlines(originalTestValue) === expectedResult)
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "altered use case ...\ntest passed ?..",
  (parseNewlines(alteredTestValue) === expectedResult)
);
console.log(
  "altered use case and altered expectation ...\ntest passed ?..",
  (parseNewlines(alteredTestValue) === expectedResultOfAlteredValue)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice way! Just one note, instead of `lastLine = rest.pop()` we can now use `lastLine = rest.at(-1)`

Comment: @AlexandrBelan ... The [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) is badly needed for one does not only want to access/assign the `lastLine` but in addition has to alter/mutate the `rest` array.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
var data =
  "Retract-A-Banner\n**Template:\nFull Color\nImprint Information:\nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing\n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network\n";

function convertToLines(entry) {
  return entry.split("\n").filter((val) => val);
}

function constructOutput(lines) {
  const numLines = lines.length;
  return lines.reduce((result, entry, index) => {
    var separator = index > 2 ? " >>>> \n" : "\n";
    if (index == numLines - 1) {
      separator = "(end)\n";
    }
    return result + entry + separator;
  }, "");
}
console.log(constructOutput(convertToLines(data)));
```

The `convertToLines` uses the `filter` to dump empty entries which you get from the new line at the end of the string.  And then we have to tack that on to the `(end)` separator`.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @mrrogers ... Did you test the above solution? The implementation features a line mis-count for the newline replacement after the first 3 lines (here it's after the 4th one)

Comment: I just did a visual test and thought I'd lined things up correctly.  Also I may have read too far into a solution by dumping empty lines with the `filter`. So I suppose this solution is close - but maybe not quite there, and likely could get tweaked a bit to address the end/blank line conditions.

Answer (score 1):

- Convert string into an array of strings

  ```
   string.split(/\n/)
  ```
- Then use `.flatMap()` and a chained ternary as callback. Each condition is based on index

  ```
    idx < 3 ? [str+' \n']
    :
    idx === arr.length -1 ? [str+' (end)'] 
    : 
    [str+' >>>> \n']
  ```
- Then `.join('')` the array back into a string

```js
let test = `Retract-A-Banner\nTemplate:\nFull Color\nImprint Information:\nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing\n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network\n" Expected Output:"Retract-A-Banner\nTemplate:\nFull Color \nImprint Information: \nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing \n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network`;

const formatLines = string => string.split(/\n/).flatMap((str, idx, arr) => idx < 3 ? [str + ' \n '] : idx === arr.length - 1 ? [str + ' (end) '] : [str + ' >>>> \n ']).join('');

console.log(formatLines(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want something like this:

```js
var strings = `Retract-A-Banner\nTemplate:\nFull Color\nImprint Information:\nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing\n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network\n`.split("\n");
strings.forEach((string,index) => {
    if (index > 2) {
       strings[index] = `>>>>\\n${string}`
    } else {
       index > 0 ? `\\n${string}` : strings[index];
    }
})
var finalString = strings.join("")+"(end)";
console.log(finalString);
```

Note that I'm escaping your `\n` in that code with an extra backslash. I cannot tell if that's what you want though.

Comment: That is exactly it,  I couldn't for the life of me get the index value. The one thing however is it's adding a \n to the beginning of the string. I would need to not have that occur.

Comment: You mean on the very first string? I updated it to eliminate that.

Comment: This is a great start,  thank you, this is very helpful

Comment: @Marc ... did you test the above solution? The result doesn't equal the value expected by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

To insert the `>>>>` you can use the regex: `(?<=(.+\n.+){2,})(?=\n.)`

- The `(?<=(.+\n.+){2,})` creates a positive lookbehind for three lines
- The `(?=\n.)` creates a positive lookahead for a newline followed by any character

And then you can use the similar regex `(?<=.)(?=\n*$)` to add `'(end)'` to the last line.

```js
const input = "Retract-A-Banner\n**Template:\nFull Color\nImprint Information:\nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing\n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network\n";

const output = input
                .replace(/(?<=(.+\n.+){2,})(?=\n.)/g, ' >>>> ')
                .replace(/(?<=.)(?=\n*$)/, '(end)');

console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```

---

If you are using a literal backslash followed by a 'n' in your string, it would be formatted as `\\\n` in your JS string literal.

In that case you can use the regex `(?<=(.+\\n.+){2,})(?=\\n.)` to insert the `>>>>` and the regex `(?=\\n$)` for the `(end)`.

```js
const input = "Retract-A-Banner\\n**Template:\\nFull Color\\nImprint Information:\\nCL: 488 Special Ops Wing\\n353 SOW Integrated Resilience Optimization Network\\n";

const output = input
                .replace(/(?<=(.+\\n.+){2,})(?=\\n.)/g, ' >>>> ')
                .replace(/(?=\\n$)/, '(end)');

console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```